# Calling a web service in a windows application form

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

**EDIT. I was adding it as a service reference instead of a web service reference (found by when adding a service refererence, go into advanced and down the bottom it should say "add web reference") , I didn't know that option existed as it's hidden away.**

I made a web service in c# .net. Initially it wasn't calling because I thought that the web form didn't like the codebehind for the web form that is created in VS2012, so I took that out and just included the web service file itself.

I'm pretty sure the libraries were included when I visit the url of the service with wsdl, but it still won't seem to call the service to the form.

It displays some XML data and shows TestCypher as a workable service, so it should be working? I'm not entirely sure where the wsdl file should be hosted if I take the web service out of the solution

Comment: First I think you should use a WCF service. WCF is the way to go. Learning this has more value for the future. There is a WCF test client available in Visual Studio. This is a good way of testing your service independent of the client.

Comment: I agree completely, and will probably get onto that for my next project, I wasn't sure how to approach it though. The web service is working, now I'm trying to test the web service by returning the string but I'm not sure how to go about it, I understand the code but I sitll have a hard time going headfirst into it. Help would be appreciated. I've updated my original post with the fix I had.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26941/Consuming-Webservice-In-A-Windows-Application

you can use this method in your application. I just post this example in your requirement.

please note : i have no guarantee about the perfomrnce area in this method.

So please consider this element when your application is use a wide number of users.

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, I was using that earlier and must have skipped over a part. My problem was that I was thinking Service References and Web References were the same thing and this led to it not loading the libraries generated in the wdsl properly I think. I didn't realise web services were so outdated when I started the project.